# Unable to copy from putty window to windows

Tags: windows, putty, copy-paste

I have turned on the "Compromise" feature within Putty configuration, but I am unable to copy in putty (highlighting with left mouse cursor) and pasting into windows (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)

I am also unable to copy from windows (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and paste into the Putty session (either via right mouse click or via <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd>).

[image: Putty Configuration]

Comment: Usually you cannot use Ctrl+C or Ctrl+V in a console window. You have to right click the titlebar and choose Edit (you may also, depending on settings, be able to right click in the window). You can turn on these keys in Properties but they do cause compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

Hightlight text.
Right mouse click on highlighted text.

Data is now copied to your clipboard.
CTRL-V to Windows.